# Maven install on mac

Tags: maven

I downloaded maven on mac and installed in \DevTools folder.

1. Created .bashrc file with below

```
alias ll='ls -al'
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home`
MAVEN_HOME=/DevTools/maven
export PATH="${PATH}:${MAVEN_HOME}/bin"
```

2. Created .bash_profile with below

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
source ~/.bashrc
fi

# Setting PATH for Python 3.7
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

closed and restarted the terminal

3. Maven is installed in \DevTools folder
   Sym link is created with below command

```
ln -s apache-maven-3.6.3 maven
```

4. When I try to run "mvn -version", it does not work
   gives error "mvn: command not found

Comment: The default shell on MacOS is now `zsh`.  I suggest you start a shell with `bash` and see if your set-up works.  You can also verify your Maven install with `env JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home) /DevTools/maven/bin/mvn`.

Comment: What does `which mvn` show?